# plpython3: can a function return a 'class' or 'generator' object to a query

Tags: networkx, postgres-plpython

I am running a docker container with a postgres image.  The image includes python3, pandas, and networkx.  The combination allows me to construct a graph from the db data all within the postgres environment.

I want to be able to retrieve the graph through a remote query to the db.  The graph exists as an entry in the GD with type `class`.  If I return it as type `text` as in the code below, I get the string `Graph with 40 nodes and 20 edges`.

```
drop function if exists GD_retrieve();
create or replace function GD_retrieve()
    returns text
language plpython3u as
$function$
    return GD['recon_G']
$function$;

select * from GD_retrieve();
```

I thought maybe running a conversion to text might work e.g. convert the graph to `graphml` (a text format) and return that as a generator.

```
drop function if exists GD_retrieve();
create or replace function GD_retrieve()
    returns text
language plpython3u as
$function$
    import networkx as nx
    graphml = nx.generate_graphml(GD['recon_G'])
    return graphml
$function$;
```

That gives a string `'<generator object generate_graphml at 0x7fe78b6b2480>'` but if I use the `cytoscape` format:

```
drop function if exists GD_retrieve();
create or replace function GD_retrieve()
    returns text
language plpython3u as
$function$
    import networkx as nx
    graph_cyto = nx.cytoscape_data(GD['recon_G'])
    return graph_cyto
$function$;
```

I get a very long string containing all the data that can be parsed or imported in to `networkx` locally or into `cytoscape` itself.  Not awful but not elegant.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to do this:

```
drop function if exists GD_retrieve();
create or replace function GD_retrieve()
    returns text[]
language plpython3u as
$function$
    import networkx as nx
    graph = GD['recon_G']  <-- networkx graph stored in global dict
    graph_alt = nx.generate_graphml(graph)  <-- returns a generator
    graphml_ser = []
    for item in graph_alt:
        graphml_ser.extend([item]) <-- use generator to build up a long string
    return graphml_ser  <-- returns a text array 
$function$;
```

So if I send a query `select * from GD_retrieve();` I get back a `graphml` string of text, essentially a serialized XML file with elements specifically related to graphs.  Again not elegant but it works.